# How to pass a vector as a parameter in rust

Tags: vector, rust

I am trying to write a function that prints a vector. I am having some trouble in understanding how to pass a vector as a parameter. This is what I have so far:

```
fn vecprinter(v1: &mut Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {

v1
}

fn main(){

  let mut v1=vec![1,10,11,12,13];
  
  println!("{:?}", vecprinter(v1));
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> main.rs:3:1
  |
1 | fn vecprinter(v1: &mut Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
  |                                     -------- expected `std::vec::Vec<u32>` because of return type
2 | 
3 | v1
  | ^^
  | |
  | expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found mutable reference
  | help: try using a conversion method: `v1.to_vec()`
  |
  = note:         expected struct `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
          found mutable reference `&mut std::vec::Vec<u32>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs:10:31
   |
10 |   println!("{:?}", vecprinter(v1));
   |                               ^^
   |                               |
   |                               expected mutable reference, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |                               help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut v1`
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::vec::Vec<u32>`
                         found struct `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
compiler exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut v1`
   |"

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues here.

Firs your `vecprinter` method takes a `&mut Vec<u32` as a parameter, but you are passing it a `Vec<u32>` in your call to `println!`. To resolve this pass a mutable reference t to the vec instead:

```rust
println!("{:?}", vecprinter(&mut v1));
```

The second issue is with the return types of the  `vecprinter` method. You are taking in a `&mut Vec<u32>` and expecting to return a `Vec<u32>`; however, when you return the value of `v1` you are returning a `&mut Vec<u32>` rather than the expected `Vec<u32>`. Depending on your requirements you have two options.

Change the return type of the `vecprinter` method and pass a mutable reference:

```rust
fn vecprinter(v1: &mut Vec<u32>) -> &mut Vec<u32> {
    v1
}

fn main(){

  let mut v1=vec![1,10,11,12,13];
  
  println!("{:?}", vecprinter(&mut v1));
}
```

or change the parameter value to take the vector rather than a reference:

```rust
fn vecprinter(v1: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    v1
}

fn main(){

  let mut v1=vec![1,10,11,12,13];
  
  println!("{:?}", vecprinter(v1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just realized this.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your question:

> I am trying to write a function that prints a vector.

But the function you wrote (no matter if it works or not) is not writing anything: it *returns* the given vector.

A function which would print something would look like this:

```
fn print_something(to_print: /*Some type*/) /*No return type*/ {
    println!(/*...*/);
}
```

As you want to print a vector of `u32`, the prototype could be:

```
fn print_something(to_print: Vec<u32>) { /*...*/ }
```

But if you do that, the argument will be *moved* into the function and will become unusable outside of it. In order to improve this, you can pass the argument as a reference:

```
fn print_something(to_print: &Vec<u32>) { /*...*/ }
```

To handle more general cases (`&Vec<u32>` + `&[u32]`), you can still improve it like this:

```
fn print_something(to_print: &[u32]) { /*...*/ }
```

Now when you call this function, you have to add an ampersamp `&` to the given argument (unless it's already a reference):

```
print_something(&my_vector);
```

Finally, by gluing everything together, you have this:

```
fn print_vec(v: &[u32]) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 10, 11, 12, 13];
    print_vec(&v);

    // Because we changed "&Vec<u32>" to "&[u32]", the following is also
    // possible:
    let arr = &[1, 10, 11, 12, 13];
    print_vec(arr);
}
```